# Turn object from API to string C#

Tags: c#, json

I am doing a bot for VK on C# and faced to some problems. I have method which returns JSON like this

```
{
    "ts": 1674111105,
    "updates": [[4,
        2262,
        17,
        61835649,
        1534493714,
        "",
        {
            "attach1_type": "doc",
            "attach1": "61835649_472186415",
            "title": " ... "
        }
    ]]
}
```

This is object, as I see, but I cant get anything from the `attach_type1` to `title` including. This is also an object, and it can't be transformed to string just like `.ToString()`, because in that case in the result I have `System.Object`. So, does anybody know how I can change this type or is it impossible?? I am in desperation.

I created a class for this object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace CSharpVKbot.VK.UserLongPoll
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class Attachment
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "attach1_type")]
        public string AttachType; 

        [DataMember(Name = "attach1")]
        public string Attach;

        [DataMember(Name = "title")]
        public string Title;
    }
}
```

created an object of this class

```
public Attachment DocId = new Attachment();
```

and then tried to change type to attachment, but it doesnt work either

```
case UpdateCode.NewMessage:
     u.MessageID = (int)item[1];
     u.Flags = (int)item[2];
     u.PeerID = (int)item[3];
     u.TimeStamp = (int)item[4];
     u.Text = (string)item[5];
     u.DocId = (Attachment)item[6];
     break;
```

Comment: Please share your c# code with us.

Comment: what do you want to do with this after you transform it to a string?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you have that json and want to turn it into an c# object? If so, you'll eventually be digging into the 6th element of that updates array, with "TheThing.updates[6].attach1_type".   If no one has given a good answer in an hour or two, I'll reveal some heresy that might help :)

Comment: I need to put it in a string variable

Comment: I have this json in object and I want it to be string

Comment: Hi Ivan, Maybe you'll be kind enough and copy the code to the question instead of giving us a link to github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialise the JSON - It cannot be just converted to an object.

Try something like

```
Attachment deserializedAttachement = new Attachment();  
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item[6]));  
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedAttachment.GetType());  
deserializedAttachment = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Attachment;  
ms.Close();
```

Where `item[6]` is the string that represents the attachment information.

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data#example

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to iterate through all json properties.

**This code may help you**

```
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(YourJsonString);

foreach (var prop in obj)
{
   if (prop is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
   {
      // Handle JObject
   }

   if (prop is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)
   {
      // Handle JProperty
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many direction to resolve your problem. 
I like it (using Newtonsoft):

```
JObject data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var attach1_type = data.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "attach1_type")
    ?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

numbers, strings, objects are in same array, which means they are `boxed` before returning to you. so your `updates` is `List<List<object>>` or `object[][]`, whatever. your c# class, which match this json format, could be simply like this:

```
public class SomethingJsonResult
{
    public int ts { get; set; }

    public List<List<object>> updates { get; set; }
}
```

The 1st option is to use [anonymous type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm):

```
    public void ParseJsonResult(SomethingJsonResult result)
    {
        var definition = new
            {
                attach1_type = "",
                attach1 = "",
                title = ""
            };


        result?.updates?.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var update = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(x[6], definition);
            var attachment = new Attachment
            {
                AttachType = update.attach1_type,
                Attach = update.attach1,
                Title = update.title,
            };
        });
    }
```

The 2nd option is a bit complex:

```
[DataContract()]
public class Attachment
{
    [DataMember(Name = "attach1_type")]
    [JsonProperty("attach1_type")] //Tell JsonConverter how to map your object
    public string AttachType { get; set; }//Here is property, but not variable

    [DataMember(Name = "attach1")]
    [JsonProperty("attach1")]
    public string Attach { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}


    public void ParseJsonResult(SomethingJsonResult result)
    {
        result?.updates?.ForEach(update =>
        {
            //(Attachment)update[6] works only when your names of properties 100% match json objects
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Attachment>(update[6])
            ....
        });
    }
```

DataContractSerializer example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

you can implement everything inside your custom converter:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttachmentWrapper>(json, new AttachmentConverter(typeof(AttachmentWrapper)));
```